# Visual Studio 2013 Unable to Retrieve Folder Information from Server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a website that is failing to load.  The solution contains 8 projects, one of which is a 'website'.  Previously the website was in another folder and I referenced that folder in the solution.  Well, I've since deleted the branch that kept the website in the other folder, and now, in the solution explorer, the website says "nameofwebsite (load failed)".  When I right-click the website and choose 'Reload Project' I get a model that says *"Unable to retrieve folder information from the server.  Cannot read from folder 'C:\Users\\Source\Workspace...\path\to\**OLD**\location\of\website'.  The system cannot find the path specified."*

I've tried clearing the TFS cache in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache, but that did not help.

Any advice is appreciated.  There's currently nothing in the solution file that mentions the folder it can't find.  In fact it's mentioning a folder that I've long since deleted...  Why does it want to look there still?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you open the solution in a text editor and checked the website  reference?

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with TFS. Instead follows @ds19 advice and check the solution file. You can also delete the website from your solution and then add it again. This should fix the incorrect paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by incorrect path to the web project in IIS.  Configuring the correct location solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, it would help quite a lot if you included the steps of what you did, cheers.

Comment: @JCO9 i agree..

Answer (score 0):

Update your IIS settings:

Steps:

1. Open IIS Settings in Windows.
2. Choose the website and click "Basic Settings"
3. Update the "Physical Path" to the correct directory.
4. When you re-open the Visual Studio solution, it will have the correct path and not error.

[image]